# Apache 2: allow access to a folder only from a specific domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

A trivial problem, but it seems I can't find a working solution.
I have a folder on a server which contains several files. I want to disable folder access to anyone, except a specific domain, from which files can be downloaded.

The files from the allowed domain are downloaded with a link

```
<a href="https://<file-in-protected-folder-url" download>Download file</a>
```

I thought it was easy, but I can't get this working with htaccess or  directives...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using the *If/Else* directives in the htaccess file to strict access by host .

```
<If "req('Host') != 'secure-folder.example.com'">
  Redirect (.*) http://www.example.com
  # Require all denied
</If>
```

More details are explained [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if)